# How to draw a gizmo in CesiumJS

Tags: cesiumjs

How to draw a gizmo by giving it a position, orientation and eventually a scale in a [CesiumJS](https://cesium.com/platform/cesiumjs/) application?

By gizmo I mean a 3-axes right-handed reference frame using (x,y,z) vectors, ideally depicted as (RGB) values, such as these, for example:

[image: Blender Gizmo]
[image: Gizmo2]
[image: Gizmo3]

I wish I could depict the orientation of any object (e.g. a glTF) by placing such reference frame, for example, at the position of the object origin (e.g. using its [longitude, latitude and elevation](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Cartesian3.html)) and following its orientation, as defined by its [heading, pitch and roll](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/HeadingPitchRoll.html) values which must follow the three given angles in their original order (heading first, pitch second and roll third) starting from the [LTP-ENU (0,0,0) convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates) (x=0=east, y=0=north, z=0=upward).

The inspector is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DebugModelMatrixPrimitive.
Here 's [Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)
Sample code

```
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

const position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-107.0, 40.0, 300000.0);

const redSphere = viewer.entities.add({
    name: "Red sphere with black outline",
    position: position,
    ellipsoid: {
        radii: new Cesium.Cartesian3(300000.0, 300000.0, 300000.0),
        material: Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
        outline: true,
        outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
    },
});

const heading = Cesium.Math.toRadians(10);
const pitch = Cesium.Math.toRadians(50);
const roll = Cesium.Math.toRadians(0);

const hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, roll);

const frame = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollToFixedFrame(position, hpr);

viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.DebugModelMatrixPrimitive({
    modelMatrix: frame,
    length: 800000,
    width: 3.0
}));

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```